# If statement confusion - how to display a div if file is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement

If file is selected show `h1` div else hide it. Maybe I have gone absolutely the wrong way in terms of calling `alert()`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function foo() {
    var f = document.getElementById("f1");
    var h = document.getElementById("h1");
    alert( ""==f.value ? " f == nothing selected" : "f = file selected");
    alert( ""==h.value ? " h == nothing selected" : "h = file selected");
    if(alert( ""==f.value "f = file selected"){
        $('#h1').show();
    }else{
        $('#h1').hide();
    }
  }
</script>
<style type="text/css">
#h1{
    display:none;
}
</style>
<input id="f1" type="file">
<input id="h1" type="file">
```

Comment: why are you alerting in an if statement ?

Comment: if the condition is true then h1 will show, if not it will hide. I wasn't sure how to tell it regarding the value.

Comment: Try `if("" == f.value)` . Also when is your `foo` function called ?

Comment: @JulianDescottes sorry that didn't work, The function `foo` is called all the time, whether the file is selected or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show and hide the second file input based on wether or not a file is selected in the first file input you'd do :

```
$('#f1').on('change', function() {
    $('#h1').toggle(this.value.length);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/WtUXG/)

Comment: Thanks for this, I wasn't approaching the problem with the correct intelligence! :D Brilliant that's what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

`alert(anything)` returns `undefined`, so it really doesn't make sense to say `if(alert(anything)){`. In your case you've just got a plain syntax error though because you've got unbalanced parentheses and inside your `alert()` you've got two statements `""==f.value "f = file selected"`.

Also to select the element with `id="h1"` you need the selector `"#h1"`, not `"h1"`.

Try this:

```
if(""==f.value){
    $('#h1').show();
}else{
    $('#h1').hide();
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/X49Pq/ (Your question doesn't say how/when you call the `foo()` function, so in my demo I just run the relevant code from a separate "Test" button but you could run it from a change handler on f1 or whatever.)